# iOS Universal apps, and nibs / xibs

Tags: ios, nib, ios-universal-app

I have a universal app in development.

The app uses NIBs, and I have, for example,

```
ExcitingViewController.xib
ExcitingViewController~iPad.xib
```

On the iPhone or iPad simulator, the appropriate variant is picked up automagically (i.e. the one with the ~iPad suffix is selected on the iPad without any code change).

However, on a real iPad the iPhone variant is always used.

I've seen mention of selecting the appropriate NIB programatically, but as this is handled automagically on the simulator, I don't see why it couldn't be on a real deice.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    excitingViewController = [[ExcitingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExcitingViewController" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    excitingViewController = [[ExcitingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExcitingViewController~iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```

Any tips on getting the ~iPad variants selected automatically on a real device?

(btw, the simulators are normally utterly dependable in exhibiting the correct behaviour, so it's annoying to find these differences / bugs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer does seem to be that you need to handle this programmatically (as shown in the question), which seems like a missed opportunity by Apple, but maybe there's more to it.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in my projects is to override initWithNibName/initWithCoder/init and check if it's an iPad, and if so load the appropriate one.

I have a macro in my pch for the iPad checking:

```
// iPad detection
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
#define IS_IPAD() (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
#define IS_IPAD() (false)
#endif
```

Then I just use IS_IPAD() in my code where needed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late to the party but have you tried something like:

- ExcitingViewController~iphone.xib
- ExcitingViewController~ipad.xib

This should be device agnostic so

```
[[ExcitingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExcitingViewController" bundle:nil]
```

should work on both devices without having to check the user interface idiom.

This is sort of covered in the [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html).